# Django Admin 'login as' button

Tags: python, django, django-admin

On user form view, add button "Login As", that button will execute functionality that we login as that user. Only admins can see/execute this functionality. This is my question, how this to make?

Can someone help me with this task

Comment: if you want to login as 'other user' that will be a violation. But if you want to login as other role that included in Admin role then there is may a way to do that. Please ask with a brief and clear question, you can read and learn again about how to ask here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Django Python packages available for this; the one I've had success with is `django-hijack`:

https://django-hijack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The interface components are very well thought out, and it contains functionality allowing you to release and return back to the admin user you were originally logged in as.